# How to get only one element by a specific condition?

Tags: jquery

I have this HTML:

```
<input type="text" value="" />
<input type="text" value="" />
<input type="text" value="" />
```

I want to select ONLY the first input field with `value=""`. How can I do that?

Comment: `$('input[value=""]:first')`

Comment: @Regent: thats good! havent thought about that. Is there another way to achieve this, if theres no value="" attribute at the element?

Comment: @Regent: NO not simply :first ... but [value=""] is an attribute selector. But its valid to not have the attribute value defined at an input field. Does the [value=""] selector work then? i guess not. And thats the problem I have

Comment: Well, then you are most probably stuck with `.filter()`. "Stuck" - because it is quite long solution, but looks like the only one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a combination of the attribute and `:first` selector:

```
$('input[value=""]:first')
```

Or the `first()` method:

```
$('input[value=""]').first();
```

Both will return you the same element.

If there is no `value` attribute defined you would need to use `filter()` to retrieve the value via the jQuery/DOM object directly:

```
$('input').filter(function() {
    return this.value == '';
}).first();
```

Comment: @ggzone thanks, was just in the process of updating.

Comment: is there a problem if the value attribute is not defined?

Comment: @ggzone yes, see my update for a solution for that. You should always include the `value` attribute though.

Comment: thats it! :) i havent used the .filter() function yet.. seems powerful! thanks a lot. will accept this in some minutes

Answer (score 0):

You can do `$("input[value=""]:first")`